# Set Environment Variables - nginx + uWSGI

Tags: nginx, flask, environment-variables, uwsgi

I want to be able to access environment variables (for passwords and such) in a Flask app.

I'm running nginx and uWSGI. Where is the correct place to set them so they're available?

Should I just add a `uwsgi_param PARAM_NAME 'param_value';` line to the config for the site (in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhere near `uwsgi_pass`, for example:

```
    location / {
            uwsgi_pass              unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
            include                 uwsgi_params;

            uwsgi_param             UWSGI_SCRIPT            webapp;
            uwsgi_param             UWSGI_CHDIR             /usr/local/www/app1;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked great. If I have a variable with a `$` in it, it seems to not like it, even if I surround it with single quotes. Is it impossible to use something like `uwsgi_param SOME_PARAM 'abc$123';`?

Comment: I`m not sure but probably must work. Or try `uwsgi_param SOME_PARAM abc$123;`

Comment: this *isn't* working... any ideas why not would be welcome. I'm not using Flask, just nginx and uwsgi. no passed uwsgi_params show up in os.environ when the Python script executes (all it does right now *is* show the environment).

Comment: never mind, I should have been using the `env` in the args to the Python app rather than `os.environ`. duh. thanks.